# A trouble about Jetpack-Compose Column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

It couldn't run successfully with the following error:

```
Cannot find a parameter with this name: crossAxisSize
```

How can I fix it? Here's my code:

```
@Composable
fun NewsStory() {
    Column(
            crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
            modifier=Spacing(16.dp)
    )
    {
        Text("demo")
        Text("try")
        Text("somethings")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or error messages. Please post all text as text.

Comment: The parameter crossAxisSize is removed from the fun Column see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-layout/src/main/java/androidx/ui/layout/Flex.kt?autodive=0%2F#356

Answer (score 1):

***Note - please see an update on this below.***

It is available on FlexColumn. Use it inside Column, like this:

```
 @Preview
@Composable
fun NewsStory() {
    Column( modifier=Spacing(16.dp)) {
        FlexColumn(
            crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand

        )
        {
            Text("demo")
            Text("try")
            Text("somethings")
        }
    }

}
```

I assume this is the result you want?

[image: This is the result]

FlexColumn:

```
@Composable fun FlexColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.None, 
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Start, 
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Start, 
    crossAxisSize: LayoutSize = LayoutSize.Wrap, 
    block: FlexChildren.() -> Unit
): Unit
```

[link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary.html#FlexColumn(androidx.ui.core.Modifier,%20androidx.ui.layout.MainAxisAlignment,%20androidx.ui.layout.CrossAxisAlignment,%20androidx.ui.layout.LayoutSize,%20kotlin.Function1))

**EDIT - Important:**
Just came to know that Flex is going to be deprecated soon. Oh the joy of working with alpha releases (: So the correct way would be to use ***Column/Row and apply Flexible modifier to the children***. Keeping this post instead of deleting as someone might still be tempted to use FlexColumn/FlexRow as they are still officially out there. Do not!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `crossAxisSize` was removed from the `Column` composable, I think in favor of using modifiers. If you want the `Column` to expand to full size, you can add the `Expanded` modifier to it, so then your code becomes like this:

```
@Composable
fun NewsStory() {
    Column(
            modifier=Expanded.wraps(Spacing(16.dp))      <<<------ the change
    )
    {
        Text("demo")
        Text("try")
        Text("somethings")
    }
}
```

Swapping the two modifiers shouldn't give a different result. You can also use either `ExpandedWidth` or `ExpandedHeight` if you only want to expand in one direction (as `crossAxisSize` actually only expands the width in case of a `FlexColumn`).

Comment: Thanks. `Column(modifier = ExpandedWidth){}` seems the most straightforward replacement